# PHP regex that accept only selected words or no word at all

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to do a regex that would accept the following:

```
/profile
/profile/photo
/profile/video
```

but would not accept anything else than /photo and /video:

I tried the following but without any luck:

```
/profile((\/(photo|video))|[^\w])/
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my regex.

Thanks

Comment: why not just do this? "/profile(/photo|/video)*"

Comment: not tested: `$\/profile(\/(photo|video))?^`

Comment: anything after `/photo` ? for eg. `../photo/blah-blah..`

Comment: You can use: `~^/profile(?:/photo|/video)?$~`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this'll work:

```
^\/profile(?:\/(photo|video))?$
```

about your *regex*: `/profile((\/(photo|video))|[^\w])/`

- `\w` matches `a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _` so `^\w` will match ***any other*** character. for eg. `profile/`, `profile%`, `profile#` will result in a match. since you've written `[^\w]` and not `[^\w]+ or *` therefore it'll match a single `non-word` character after `profile*here*`
- you've not prepended `profile` with a `/`

derived from what you've written, this'll work too:

```
^\/profile(\/(photo|video))?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^\/profile(\/photo|\/video|)?$/
```

Comment: matches `/photo` of `/photo/etc-etc`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^\/profile(\/photo|\/video)?$
```

Here you have a working example:

http://regex101.com/r/iE2yJ4/1

[image]

Comment: a forward slash only has to be escaped in a regex when the delimiters are forward slashes too